# Go bindings for Subversion

Tags: svn, go

Has anyone written Go bindings for Subversion? By that I mean for programmatic access to the [Subversion API](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/api/latest/). If not I'll consider writing some.

I looked in these places:

- http://go-lang.cat-v.org/library-bindings
- http://godashboard.appspot.com/
- https://www.google.com/search?q=golang+subversion
- https://www.google.com/search?q=golang+svn

Comment: @dystroy: Thanks, edited the question to explain. I meant a Go wrapper for the Subversion API.

Comment: I'd recommend you to ask [golang-nuts](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/golang-nuts) but you may very well be the first to want that.

Comment: maybe an option to consider: google itself for their own depo tool, once chose to shell out to the svn command, that was for a python tool, with Go it'd be [Run](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Run)

Comment: Another great place to check for packages is http://go.pkgdoc.org

Comment: You can see my search result on https://golanglibs.com/search?q=svn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there aren't any existing SVN bindings, or at least nothing outstanding. Here are the results on [GitHub](https://github.com/search?langOverride=&q=language%3Ago+svn&repo=&start_value=1&type=Repositories), though perhaps that's not the best place to check for SVN tools. As @PW suggested, you might try invoking the system shell for SVN tasks. That might be suboptimal, but it depends on how much effort you'd want to put into developing bindings. If you do, they'll definitely be appreciated.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Masterminds/vcs 
Supports - **Git, SVN, Bazaar (Bzr), and Mercurial (Hg)**

https://github.com/assembla/svn2go 
its wrapper around libsvn-dev.

https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/go/vcs 
Go tooling around VCS